# SharePoint Online -- Workflow Based on Contents of Field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list with a field called "Must Confirm" which is optional and may contain multiple team members.  When an item is added to the list, I want an approval process to start for the team members in the "Must Confirm" field.  If there are no team members, nothing should happen.  If there is at least one, then I want to require approvals from each one.

I can't figure out how to do either of those things: to only start the approval process if there are any entries in "Must Confirm", and to require approval from everyone in "Must Confirm".  I am brand new to SharePoint, so I'm hoping there is an obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Designer 2013 you can create a custom workflow and specify the conditions that need to be met for an action to start. In your case it sounds like you want the workflow to start when an item is created, and with designer you can use a condition saying if field x equals y, start a task process, else go to end of workflow.